# Interior wall appears to have missing stud. What's going on?

Tags: walls, studs, shelving

I'm mounting some simple Rubbermaid-type shelves to the wall. (One upright track is affixed to each stud, and brackets are used to attach each shelf to the uprights.)

The wall is typical interior construction, drywall over wood studs, spaced 16" on-center.

Three of the four uprights attached fine; however, when attempting to mount the final upright, I found no stud where there should be one. I measured 16" from the center of the adjacent stud, and an electric studfinder seems to detect a stud there. A strong magnet shows something (drywall screws?) above and below the drill location. A pilot hole clearly shows nothing behind the drywall, though.

Two additional pilot holes drilled slightly to the left and slightly left-and-below felt like they hit a stud. (Perhaps the stud was incorrectly spaced?) However, when attempting to follow up with a screw, I encountered drastically increased resistance as if the screw was hitting something decidedly not-a-stud. I stopped short (approx 1.5" of screw had entered the wall) and removed the screw.

There are no electrical boxes or other fixtures that appear to be mounted to that "stud" position on either side of the wall. There is a small HVAC closet on the other side of the wall, but it is approx 1.5 feet to the side; I don't think I'm hitting anything related to that.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: It sounds like there might be a knot there.  Knots usually denser than the usual wood of a stud.  Drywall is usually about 1/2", so you seem to be going another inch into something.  Metal plates should be used when there is cable or pipes in a stud, sometimes they are not there.

Comment: pipes and electrical are supposed to be 3/4" from the face of the stud or have nail protection.  3/4" + 1/2" drywall = 1 1/4" (the standard length of drywall screws).  Studs can wrap after installation so possibly you just hit an area where the stud has bowed out of plumb.

Comment: Shouldn't bow that much! Especially if it was screwed to the drywall. It is entirely possible that a stud was mismeasured or, possibly, put on the wrong side of the marks on the top/bottom plate. It shouldn't happen, but it can, especially if the wall was DIYed by the previous owner.

Comment: @crip659 I remeasured the screw's entry depth: only 1 1/8", less than I thought.

Could this be a knot? Measuring the depth of a second hole 2" below the first, I can still only insert a screw 1 1/8" into the wall before significant tension.

My screws are 2" long in total, but the upright tracks themselves put about 1/2" between the underside of the screwhead and the drywall.

Comment: @CompuCat  Usually knot holes that big should not be in structural 2x4s, maybe not even in second rate ones.  You said that the screw is only harder to drive/turn, it is not stopping like hitting metal.  Cable or plastic should be easy to go into, but not good idea.

Comment: @crip659 It did stop moving forward. I felt like I could have kept pushing further in with enough force, but the sudden increase in force required made be stop and think.

What on earth would be at that depth, though?

Comment: How old is the house?  100 year old wood can turn quite hard.  I had standard spade bits smoking when drilling through 100 year old doug fir bottom plates.